# How to calculate the average age of users using their birth dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to calculate the average age of users using their birth dates. I have a Model class called `Member`, including a function to get the age of the user.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Member extends Model {
    public static function averageAge() {
        //What to do here
    }

    public function age() {
        $birthDate = Carbon::parse($this->birthDate);
        return $birthDate->diffInYears(Carbon::now());
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your definition of `middle ages`?

Comment: @MarkBaker 5th to 15th century?

Comment: The column should be declared `DATE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carbon *has* a method to calculate the “age” of a date, so you can do this in your model instead:

```php
class Member extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'birthDate' => 'date',
    ];

    public function getAgeAttribute()
    {
         return $this->birthDate->age;
    }
}
```

If you’re wanting to calculate the average age of multiple members, then I’d create a class that takes a collection of members and returns that value:

```php
class AverageAge
{
    public static function forMembers(Collection $members)
    {
        return $members->average(function ($member) {
            return $member->age;
        });
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```php
$members = Member::where(...)->get();

$averageAge = AverageAge::forMembers($members);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much .
I have another question about date that come in form request is it a Carbon object or we have to parse it ?

Comment: @BettyDM No problem! Anything that comes in a form request will be a string, so you’ll need to parse it if you want a `Carbon` instance.

Comment: Don't you need to subtract the birthdate from the current date to get the age??

Comment: @RickJames I don’t really know what you’re pointing out on this 4-year-old answer? As per the answer, the Carbon library has that `age` helper to get the age in years for a particular date compared to today’s. There’s no manual subtraction—nor any other operation—going on here.