# Laravel average value on accessor

Tags: laravel, accessor

I need to calculate average age of user.

here is my accessor code

```
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    if ($this->birthday)
        return Carbon::parse($this->birthday)->age;
    else
        return 'Unknown';
}
```

How can i calculate the average age from accessor?
Thanks for any help..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the average age of users using their birth dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47040717/how-to-calculate-the-average-age-of-users-using-their-birth-dates)

Comment: What's the "average" age of a user? Isn't that just the age? Do you mean the average age among all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User.php:

```
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
  if ($this->birthday)
    return Carbon::parse($this->birthday)->age;
  else
    return 'Unknown';
}
```

If you want to calculate the average age of ALL users, place this where you need it:

```
User:all()
    ->where('age', '!=', 'Unknown')
    ->avg('age');
```

This will simply not include the users without a birth date, as it wouldn't make sense.

If the `birthday` attribute is in the users table, it will be more efficient to not select users without a birthday date:

```
User:whereNotNull('birthday')
    ->get()
    ->avg('age');
```

Comment: thanks, but my user have almost 100,000 i will be very slow after i added. Any way can improve it?

Comment: If you don't need a precise result every time the request is done, you can cache the average age for a day or so

Answer (score 0):

Property age for Carbon object not exist.

You can use diffInYears with actual date to compute the age

```
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    if ($this->birthday)
        return Carbon::now()->diffInYears(Carbon::parse($this->birthday));
    else
        return 'Unknown';
}
```

In your model you can add protected property $dates in order to retreive derectly a Carbon object and don't parse.

Comment: `age` is not documented but it does exists